# Using KnockOn with the LG G3 over top of widgets

Tags: screen, lg, power-on, lg-g3

I've just recently bought an LG G3 (D850) and I've been enjoying the KnockOn feature (where you can double tap to power the screen on/off) but I've noticed that the feature does not work over top of apps/widgets. To explain, when the screen is on (and every available spot is filled with an app or widget) the only spot I can double tap to turn it off is the very top notification bar. Now although this is only a slight inconvenience, it makes the screen much easier to turn on than off. Basically my question is:

**Is there a setting to allow the "KnockOn" feature to work over top of apps/widgets? Allowing for me to double tap anywhere on a powered on screen to turn it off.**

Thanks in advanced!